# How to Convert from Treeview to JSON in C#

Tags: c#

I am following [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfdFdW)

shown above is an example of the data I loaded in a treeview[image]

The output file that gets generated looks like this.

```
[
  "TreeNode: name",
  "TreeNode: age",
  "TreeNode: John Doe",
  "TreeNode: 35"
]
```

How can I make it look like this?

```
{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "age": 35
}
```

This is code that I am using to extract the data.

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
         Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new TreeConverter() },
         Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
                           
    var Nodes = GetChildren(SettingsView.TopNode);
    
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Nodes, settings);
   Console.WriteLine(json);
    
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Sample Schema\example.txt", json);
```

## Get Children

```
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetChildren(TreeNode Parent)
        {
            return Parent.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Concat(
                   Parent.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().SelectMany(GetChildren));
        }
```

## TreeConverter Class

```
public class TreeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(Node<Person>));
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Node<Person> node = (Node<Person>)value;
            JObject obj = new JObject();
            obj.Add("Name", node.Value.name);
            obj.Add("Age", node.Value.age);
            obj.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

## Person Class

```
public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of `SelectMany` is to flatten something like a tree into a single collection. That does not appear to be your goal, but your goal isn't entirely clear from the code you've provided. You may want to include all of your code, or if that is too much, a Minimal Reproducible Example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It all seems very complicated when I guess you should be looking at something like:

```
var x = rootNodes.Select(r => new Person(){
  name = r.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Text,
  age = Convert.ToInt32(r.Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Text)
});
```

Then serialize `x`, which is an enumerable of Person (and a point on that; you've asked for json that isn't a collection/array etc but is just (the properties of) a single Person. If you have more nodes in your tree you won't be able to get a single object out, so I presume the lack of `[ ]` in your "I want this json" is a typo?

Comment: I'm was trying to get my head around something trivial. The actual data I will be working on will have arrays. I managed to solve the issue above for a flat structure.